# Improve grouping in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection (Child Collection) on which I am performing some operation to make another collection (Parent Collection). But that I do in a dirty `foreach` loop. I want to do it in an elegant way.

```
GroupInfo grpInfo;
List<GroupInfo> lstGroupInfo = new List<GroupInfo>();
foreach (AddressInfo addressInfo in subDetails)
{
 if (lstGroupInfo.Where(u => u.Addres1 == addressInfo.Address1).Count() > 0)
    {
        grpInfo = lstGroupInfo.Where(u => u.Addres1 == addressInfo.Address1).SingleOrDefault();                                  

        if (addressInfo.Rural)
            grpInfo.Rural = true;
        else if (addressInfo.Urban)
            grpInfo.Urban = true;

        grpInfo.SubDetails.Add(addressInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        grpInfo = new GroupInfo();    
        grpInfo.AddressID = addressInfo.AddressID;
        grpInfo.LocationID = addressInfo.NamedLocationID;

        if (addressInfo.Rural)
            grpInfo.Rural = true;
        else if (addressInfo.Urban)
            grpInfo.Urban = true;

    }
}
```

`GroupInfo` class is:

```
public class GroupInfo
{
    public string Address1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int AddressID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? LocationID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I want to do it in LINQ lambda way.

Comment: You need to tidy up the code sample, it's very difficult to figure out what some of the variables are.

For example, what type is lstGroupInfo? or tripAddressInfo?

Comment: Thanks for analyzing the query, i have updated the code. Kindly tell me if i could help me more.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a lot of logic in there, so I doubt you will get there completely by using LINQ, and, more importantly, if it would actually be ***more*** elegant.

I would rewrite as follows, and be done with it:

```
        foreach (AddressInfo addressInfo in subDetails)
        {
            grpInfo = lstGroupInfo.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Address1 == addressInfo.Address1);
            if (grpInfo != null)
            {
                grpInfo.Rural = addressInfo.Rural;
                grpInfo.Urban = addressInfo.Urban;
                grpInfo.SubDetails.Add(addressInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                grpInfo = new GroupInfo();
                grpInfo.AddressID = addressInfo.AddressID;
                grpInfo.LocationID = addressInfo.NamedLocationID;
                grpInfo.Rural = addressInfo.Rural;
                grpInfo.Urban = addressInfo.Urban;
            }
        }
```

In addition, it seems to me that `Rural` and `Urban` are mutually exclusive, so why not define an enumeration that contains those two (or more) values, or declare one boolean property `IsRural` to indicate if it's "Rural", and if not, it's urban. That would bring the code down to:

```
        foreach (AddressInfo addressInfo in subDetails)
        {
            grpInfo = lstGroupInfo.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Address1 == addressInfo.Address1);
            if (grpInfo != null)
            {
                grpInfo.IsRural = addressInfo.IsRural;
                grpInfo.SubDetails.Add(addressInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                grpInfo = new GroupInfo();
                grpInfo.AddressID = addressInfo.AddressID;
                grpInfo.LocationID = addressInfo.NamedLocationID;
                grpInfo.IsRural = addressInfo.IsRural;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Shouldnt the first if-clause state if(grpInfo != null) ? It will now generate an NullReferenceException if grpInfo actually is null. Good refactoring though, makes it much more readable

Comment: Thanks Willem, but this is not exactly as expected, if you look at my more carefully, I intentially write IF condition on IsRural and IsUrban property, in your scenario it will be true or false as per the last addressInfo, but i want it to remains true if it is set to true once through out the process.

Comment: @Manvinder: MaybeI'm missing something, but I think yours will also reflect the state of the last AddressInfo in the loop.

Comment: yes but it will update only if the value is true and not false

Comment: @Manvinder: Ah yes, I see. Then you'd need to bring those checks back in. It also leads to the second part of my answer: Why is there a Rural and Urban property? They seem mutually exclusive (can they both be false btw?). An enumeration or one boolean property seems more appropriate. But I don't have the design, nor the requirements, so I can't really tell.